# Getting JSONObject from String

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

How can I get a `JSONObject` from a `HttpServletRequest` in servlets?

Comment: Have you searched, read, tried anything?

Comment: @Bozho has a good point.  There are a number of JSON libraries for Java, and I expect many of them use that class name.

Comment: when in doubt, assume it's the reference JSON library from json.org

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Very simple:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("WHATEVER"));
```

Edit: Since you use json-lib, it's

```
JSONObject o = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(request.getParameter("WHATEVER"));
```

for you.

Comment: JSONObject does not have any constructor with String argument

which API you are using ??

Comment: I'm using the JSON library from json.org.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you must be using the `net.sf.json.JSONObject` version of JSONObject **(this is not the json.org version**).

For the `net.sf.json.JSONObject` version simply use

```
JSONObject.fromObject(Object obj)
```

where `obj` is either

- a valid JSON formatted string
- a Bean POJO with getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

See [`JSONObject(java.lang.String`)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29). This will create a `JSONObject` object if you're passing in a String that is valid JSON. The constructor throws a `JSONException` so you will have to handle that. This is just as well if you are sending in invalid JSON.

It really depends on what you are doing. For the most part, JSONObject will use bean getters to create your JSON object (if you pass a bean to the constructor). Otherwise you can pass an object along with a String array of names. Here, `JSONObject` will use reflection to figure out the public members of the object. It will then use the names you provide as the keys to this object.

`JSONObject` will handle anything of type `Map` without a problem. But if your object is a `List`, you need to use `JSONArray`. Another problem is if your `Map` contains a `List`. Then, for some reason, `JSONObject` can't figure out that it is a `List` and will use the standard String representation of the `List` (not what you want). The only way to handle that is to iterate over the `Map` and built the `JSONObject` manually.

As far as your question goes, I'm assuming that you have a servlet which has an action that will return JSON. In that case, make a new `JSONObject` and use the `PrintWriter` to and `jsonObject.toString()` to output your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

GSON is a fairly good Java-based JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it a bit the *hard way*. There's certainly an easier way to do this. Just send as normal request parameters, not as JSON. You can use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to gather all form fields as parameters. Here's a kickoff example of how the JSP should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#form').submit(function() {
                    $form = $(this);
                    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
                        alert(response); // "OK"
                    });
                    return false;
                });        
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="register" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is how the servlet which listens on an `url-pattern` of `/register/*` can look like:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println(username + "," + password);
    response.getWriter().write("OK"); // You can write JSON string here.
}
```

With the [jQuery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) plugin it'll be more transparent.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#form').ajaxForm(function(response) {
                    alert(response); // "OK" 
                });        
            });
```

---

To respond back from servlet to jQuery, it's easier if you return real JSON data. For example:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
if (userDAO.exist(username)) {
    data.put("success", false);
    data.put("message", "Username in use, please choose another");
} else {
    userDAO.create(username, password);
    data.put("success", true);
    data.put("message", "User successfully registered");
}
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(data)); // Gson = Google Gson.
```

and then in jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
                $('#message').addClass(data.success ? 'success' : 'error').text(data.message).show();
            });        
        });
```

Comment: The question is not related to jQuery nor JavaScript at all, this answer is OT.